# Download an OPEN Web Page

Tags: powershell

I have a page that has content I need.  It's an internal site, so I can't give the URL.  To get to the page, there's a login page to go through first.  If I'm logged into the first page in Internet Explorer, I can run

```
START "http://whatever.com/pageIwant.asp"
```

and see the page I want in a new tab, but if I try anything like

```
$webreq = Invoke-WebRequest "http://whatever.com/pageIwant.asp"
$webreq.Content | Out-File "C:\pageIwant.htm"
```

or

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( "http://whatever.com/pageIwant.asp", 'C:\pageIwant.htm' )
```

or

```
$web = New-Object Net.WebClient
$web | Get-Member
$content = $web.DownloadString("http://whatever.com/pageIwant.asp")
```

I always get the same error:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server
returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
At line:1 char:1
+ (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( "http://pdt.inside.up ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebExceptionIf I use the `Invoke-WebRequest
```

on the login page, I can download the page, which leads me to believe the new instance of IE requires me to log into the first page again before I can get to the page I want.

The best I can come up with is to look for a way for PowerShell to use an open instance of IE where I have the page pulled up and save that, or to somehow save the page as I open it with a `START "http://whatever.com/pageIwant.asp"` command.

Is either option possible?  Am I doing this all wrong?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Error 500 is an error on the server side, not on the client side. This must probably be investigated on the server. Nothing we could tell you when we don't even know the actual URL.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the error.  I'm more looking for a way to get PowerShell to download a web page from the instance I already have open, or something along those lines.

Comment: You could inspect the request your browser is sending when you refresh the page after being authenticated  (e.g. with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) and modify the request you're sending via `Invoke-WebRequest` accordingly.

Comment: I'll look into Fiddler.  Still hoping there's an easier way though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I went the lazy route and did a `start "pageIwant.asp"` after I log in manually and did a series of sendkeys to just download the page.  Quite hacky, but I'm no pro.  Do you think I should provide that as an answer?

Comment: I would consider that too specialized for your particular scenario to be of actual use to anyone else.